# I am getting a java.sql.sqlexception: Invalid column index error using a CallableStatement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am using an insert query for a CallableStatement.  This is my query as a String:

```
String strInsert = "INSERT INTO this_table (loc_nbr, rpt_nbr, rpt_type, office_code, date_submitted, rpt_seq, alcohol, drugs, cyber, priority) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'HOME', sysdate, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

The CallableStatement I am using is:

```
CallableStatement cs = Connection.prepareCall(strInsert);
cs.setString(1, "'" + strLocationNumber + "'");
cs.setString(2, "'" + strReportNumber + "'");
cs.setString(3, "'" + strReportType + "'");
cs.setString(6, "'" + strReportSeq + "'");
cs.setString(7, "'" + strAlcohol + "'");
cs.setString(8, "'" + strDrugs + "'");
cs.setString(9, "'" + strCyber + "'");
cs.setString(10, "'" + strPriority + "'");
cs.execute();
```

Upon running this, I get a `java.sql.SQLException:  Invalid column index`

I am currently using Oracle for the database and I would like to exactly why am I receiving this error.

Comment: Why you use CallableStatement instead of a prepared statement. And also could you provide a screenshot of this_table data

Comment: I don't have the ability to post a screenshot of this_table data.  I did not think about using PreparedStatement as opposed to CallableStatement but I went with what I believe will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the indication that the table structure and the insert statement via Callable has a mismatch in the columns available and provided in query

Java wraps this exception to get more insight on the callable/prepared/sql statement.

The placeholder index correction is needed check for the `?` and then move your hardcoded value to the far end from in-between like `HOME and sysdate` and then the continuity of the placeholder index would work well.

```
String strInsert = "INSERT INTO this_table (loc_nbr, rpt_nbr, rpt_type,  rpt_seq, alcohol, drugs, cyber, priority,office_code,date_submitted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,'HOME', sysdate,);";

CallableStatement cs = Connection.prepareCall(strInsert);
cs.setString(1, "'" + strLocationNumber + "'");
cs.setString(2, "'" + strReportNumber + "'");
cs.setString(3, "'" + strReportType + "'");
cs.setString(4, "'" + strReportSeq + "'");
cs.setString(5, "'" + strAlcohol + "'");
cs.setString(6, "'" + strDrugs + "'");
cs.setString(7, "'" + strCyber + "'");
cs.setString(8, "'" + strPriority + "'");
cs.execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setString()` index number is supposed to refer to the n'th occurrence of the `?` placeholder.

Your query has two hardcoded values

```
'HOME', sysdate
```

they are not counted as placeholder indexes.